# Azure Devops - Python $(Pipeline.Workspace) - How to store a file

Tags: python, azure-devops

Im trying to store a certificate response as a text with Python Yaml on Azure Devops. I now get a Syntax error, in the code below. but I also don't know how to store a file in the $(Pipeline.Workspace) folder of azure devops. Googled but couldn't find any thing. Any ideas?
THanks

```
 response    = requests.post(f"{GATEWAY_URL}/certificate/download/format?gwsource={GATEWAY_SOURCE}", headers=headers, json=payload, verify="$(API_GATEWAY_CERT)")

    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    filename = $(Pipeline.Workspace) + '/' + COMMONNAME + '_' + timestamp + '.cer'
    
    with open(filename,  "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Comment: Hi Bart, there is something wrong with your usage, please refer to my example directly. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

To utilise any Azure DevOps variable in python you need to use os.environ['Name']. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables), predefined variables are converted into uppercase and any '.' are replace with '_'

As such, in order to access this value in python you would use the following:

```
import os
os.environ['PIPELINE_WORKSPACE']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your usage, please refer to my example directly:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import requests
      import datetime
      
      #Get the repo of DevOps via REST API(zip format data, please ignore this step, this step only for get data.) 
      
      url = "https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/git/repositories/<Repository Name>/items/items?path=/&versionDescriptor[versionOptions]=0&versionDescriptor[versionType]=0&versionDescriptor[version]=<Branch Name>&resolveLfs=true&$format=zip&api-version=5.0&download=true"
      
      payload={}
      headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic <Personal Access Token>',
      }
      
      response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
      
      #############################################################################
      #Save the zip file to current directory(The below logic is what you want.)

      COMMONNAME = "TestResults"
      timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
      filename = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)" + '/' + COMMONNAME + '_' + timestamp + '.zip'
      with open(filename, "wb") as f:
          f.write(response.content)

#Check whether the file exists.
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```